# Session dropped using combination of Azure, Https, and Remote HTTP calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, azure, https

We have an ASP.NET MVC web role running on Azure. The entire site requires https, using the [RequireHttps] attribute. As part of the site, we have integration with a credit card payment gateway.

A user can log in and everything is fine no matter how long they stay on the site or which page they go to, until they get to the payment step.  Payments involve the following:

1. User clicks "Buy" and their cart information is POSTed to Controller Action One.
2. Controller Action One.

   1. Send an http request from the server to the payment processor's API to get a unique form action URL.
   2. Present the user with a form that collects payment information.
3. That form is then POSTed directly from the browser to the payment processor using the form action URL from step 2.
4. The payment processor redirects the browser to Controller Action Two, with a token.
5. Controller Action Two

   1. We use the token to send a final request from the server to the payment processor that completes the transaction.
   2. We present the user with a success page.

Somewhere during the payment process, the user's session is dropped.  We are not explicitly logging anyone out or doing anything else that seems like it would cause this.

Other useful information:

- We only have one instance running, so we are using InProc session and not AppFabric.
- Local test server is fine. Everything is set up identically where possible.
- Everything is fine in the Azure emulator (as far as I can test it.  a full test would require the payment gateway accessing the emulator, which is not possible).
- The authentication cookies are still intact in the browser.
- Everything is happening within the session timeout window.
- If I turn off https and everything runs over http then everything is fine.

What could be causing the user's session to be dropped? It must be a result of combining Azure, https, and remote http requests because if I take one of these out of the equation then everything works.

Comment: Are you using iframes? Also, use Fiddler to see if the session cookie is being reset after the redirect from the payment processor.

Comment: Also, when the payment processor redirects back to your site is it https?

Comment: No iframes.  The redirect is https.

Comment: Check the session cookie and see if it is being reset at some point.

Comment: The session cookie is being reset after the redirect in step 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect, Asp.Net will delete session tokens. There is a boolean that can disable session deletion. Try:

```
Response.Redirect(vm.ReturnUrl, false);
```

**Edit**

Actually, Azure does load-balancing and you CANNOT guess which worker will get a given session. So you use either:

1. Cookies
2. Azure Shared Session Cache

Source: [Azure Asp.Net Redirect destroys Session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561217/azure-asp-net-redirect-destroys-session-variables)